# Shifting focus to accordion element when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, accordion

I have this accrodion: http://jsfiddle.net/ksqzg3Ld/

```
P.S: Dont remove the <br> tags. They have been put intentionally
```

I want to shift the focus to the accordion element when clicked. For eg: When Accordion section #2 or Accordion section #3 is clicked, the scroll should automatically go down and focus on the accordion section data. Is there any way to achieve this?

Essentially, my accordion will be displayed on my web page with half of it visible to the user from the bottom. I dont want the user to scroll down by himself to read the accordion element data when the element is clicked

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e){
         var currentAttrvalue = $(this).attr('href');
         if($(e.target).is('.active')){
             $(this).removeClass('active');
             $('.accordion-section-content:visible').slideUp(300);
         } else {
             $('.accordion-section-title').removeClass('active').filter(this).addClass('active');
             $('.accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).filter(currentAttrvalue).slideDown(300);
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: seems to its working: https://jsfiddle.net/5u8j21cw/ But if i missed something you have `scrollIntoView` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp

Comment: Nope. Dont remove the br elements. I want the user to click on the other element as well.. you are giving a lot of space when my actual data may not be that much.

Comment: There are no br tags in your fiddle... I didn't remove anything.

Comment: Updated the fiddle

Comment: Your window or data has got no room to scroll down in your example. Make a reproducible example, with rest of the "data"  and body because Im confused of what are you trying to achieve. also research `element.getBoundingClientRect();` and `window.scrollTo`

Comment: And from your own example it is working when you add more space to window. Eg: put your br's down also.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line at the end of the click function: `$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(currentAttrvalue).offset().top - 10}, 0);`

```html
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e){
         var currentAttrvalue = $(this).attr('href');
         if($(e.target).is('.active')){
             $(this).removeClass('active');
             $('.accordion-section-content:visible').slideUp(300);
         } else {
             $('.accordion-section-title').removeClass('active').filter(this).addClass('active');
             $('.accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).filter(currentAttrvalue).slideDown(300);
         }
         $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(currentAttrvalue).offset().top - 10}, 0);
     });
 });
```